# How to convert tag cloud from mysql to mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to convert tag cloud from mysql to mysqli to avoid SQL injections.

Here is MySQL code which is working fine:

```
<?php

$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "tags";

mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_name);

function tag_info() { 
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags GROUP BY tag ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 30"); 
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $arr[$row['tag']] = $row['count'];
  } 
  ksort($arr); 
  return $arr; 
}

function tag_cloud() {

    $min_size = 12;
    $max_size = 25;

    $tags = tag_info();

    $minimum_count = min(array_values($tags));
    $maximum_count = max(array_values($tags));
    $spread = $maximum_count - $minimum_count;

    if($spread == 0) {
        $spread = 1;
    }

    $cloud_html = '';
    $cloud_tags = array(); // create an array to hold tag code
    foreach ($tags as $tag => $count) {
        $size = $min_size + ($count - $minimum_count) 
            * ($max_size - $min_size) / $spread;
        $cloud_tags[] = '<a style="padding:5px 5px 10px 5px; font-size: '. floor($size) . 'px' 
            . '" class="tag_cloud" href="search.php?q=' . $tag 
            . '" title="\'' . $tag  . '\' returned a count of ' . $count . '">' 
            . htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($tag)) . '</a>';
    }
    $cloud_html = join("\n", $cloud_tags) . "\n";
    return $cloud_html;

}

?>
```

I just need to convert this script into mysqli, I have tried to convert it using this code:

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'usbw');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'tags');

$conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf(mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

function tag_info($conn) 
{
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM tags GROUP BY tag ORDER BY count LIMIT 20");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$arr[$row['tag']] = $row['count'];
}
ksort($arr);
return $arr;
}
function tag_cloud() {
$min_size = 12;
$max_size = 25;
$tags = tag_info($conn);
$minimum_count = min(array_values($tags));
$maximum_count = max(array_values($tags));
$spread = $maximum_count - $minimum_count;
if($spread == 0) {
$spread = 1;
}
$cloud_html = '';
$cloud_tags = array(); // create an array to hold tag code
foreach ($tags as $tag => $count) {
$size = $min_size + ($count - $minimum_count)
* ($max_size - $min_size) / $spread;
$cloud_tags[] = '<a style="padding:5px 5px 10px 5px; font-size: '. floor($size) . 'px'
. '" class="tag_cloud" target="_blank" href="tags.php?q=' . $tag
. '" title="\'' . $tag . '\' returned a count of ' . $count . '">'
. htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($tag)) . '</a>';
}
$cloud_html = join("\n", $cloud_tags) . "\n";
return $cloud_html;
}
?>
```

but it keeps giving me errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: conn on line 14
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given on line 14
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in on line 15
>
> Warning: ksort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given on line 18
>
> Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given on line 25
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 33

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: take the error message and go lookup those function names in the php docs to see what parameters are expected and in what order, and then fix the code

Comment: thanks @developerwjk .. if i knew how to fix this i would never post this at stack overflow..

Comment: And you want to get into the habit of validating return values from functions before using them in other functions.

Comment: Ok, nevermind, its a variable scope problem. So I can answer this.

Comment: Following your edit, the problem remains the same, just with a different function. This time it is `tag_cloud()` that does not have `$conn` in scope. Please update the errors you are now getting - clearly the line numbers cannot be the same.

Comment: yes you right, i have missed the $conn in 2 places out side of the function codes but its done now and working fine.. thanks every one.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variable scope problem. Your `$conn` variable is in the global scope, but functions don't have access to that unless absolutely specified with the `global` keyword.  So you have two options.

Either, use the `global` keyword (not generally considered very good practice):

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'tags');

$conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
....
function tag_info() 
{
  global $conn; //so the function can access $conn
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM tags GROUP BY tag ORDER BY count LIMIT 20");
  ...
}
...
tag_info(); //call to function
```

OR

Pass the variable to the function (generally considered better practice):

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'tags');

$conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
....
function tag_info($conn) 
{
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM tags GROUP BY tag ORDER BY count LIMIT 20");
  ...
}
...
tag_info($conn); //call to function
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this a variable scope problem?  I would try passing $conn as a parameter to tag_info(). In other words call it like this: tag_info($conn)

Comment: Seems I can't post a comment on the other thread but I looked over your new code and you are passing $conn incorrectly..  You need to pass $conn to every function, including tag_cloud(), not jut tag_info()

Comment: Let me explain a little better. tag_cloud() is the function that calls tag_info() and you did add $conn as a parameter to that function.  BUT you did not pass $conn to tag_cloud() so as far as tag_cloud() is concerned $conn does not exist.  Therefore, you are not really passing $conn to tag_info() because it does not exist in tag_cloud().

Answer (score -1):

Consider this code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));
tag_info($con);

function tag_info($con) { 
  $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tags GROUP BY tag ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 30'");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $arr[$row['tag']] = $row['count'];
  } 
  ksort($arr); 
  return $arr; 
}
```

Comment: @halfer in that case, you can pass the connection as a variable. Check my update.

Comment: @halfer did that work for you?

Comment: @halfer oh my bad. I left it there for documentation, but thank you.

Comment: Yes, we prefer to polish answers - in general "update" and "edit" sections are not necessary, since the revision history system is so good.

Comment: @Halfer as well as, technically above the update section, the code was wrong due to scoping issues.